# Detecting programmatic change of radio button in Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button

You can see in my example that clicking the radio manually fires an alert, but clicking the check/uncheck links - which do it programmatically - does not.

https://codepen.io/PeteWilliams/pen/xxXLpYE

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
      
    <script>
    
        $(document).ready(function() {
    
    
            $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
                alert(' changed');
            });
    
    
    });
    
    </script>
    </head>
      <body>
    
    
            <p>
                <label for="radio1" > RADIO BUTTON
                <input id="radio1" type="radio" />
            </label>
            </p>
    
            <p>
                <a href="#" onclick="$('#radio1').prop('checked', true ); return false;">check</a>
            </p>
    
            <p>
                <a href="#" onclick="$('#radio1').prop('checked', false ); return false;">uncheck</a>
            </p>
    
      </body>
    </html>
```

It looks like .change() only fires on user interaction, not just *any* change.

Is there another way I can achieve this goal? In this instance, I cannot change the code that selects/deselects the radio, only the code that selects it.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the `change` event is not raised if you update the input programmatically. A way of doing this with jQuery would be to use the `.trigger()` function to manually raise the event:

```js
function check() {
  const radio = $("#radio1");
  radio.prop('checked', true);
  radio.trigger('change')
}

function uncheck() {
  const radio = $("#radio1");
  radio.prop('checked', false);
  radio.trigger('change')
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
        alert('changed');
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label for="radio1" > RADIO BUTTON</label>
    <input id="radio1" type="radio" />

    <p>
      <a href="#" onclick="check()">check</a>
    </p>

    <p>
      <a href="#" onclick="uncheck()">uncheck</a>
    </p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Source: https://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately in this instance I cannot change the checking/unchecking behaviour - I need to be able to detect it independently.

Comment: @PeteWilliams are you not able to override the `onclick` function of the elements at the same time?